# The requested URL /wp-login.php was not found on this server

Tags: wordpress, web, url, server

I created a site on my local pc .../htdocs/wordpress/(all the sites files). Now, I need to transfer my site to the server. I am using FileZilla.

I transferred all my sites files to the /www directory, the wp-config.php points to the database correctly. I also imported my local database to the server database and changed the wp_options table's `home` and `siteurl` values to this url: `http://wwwhello.com/`.

Then, in the WordPress admin dashboard Settings page I changed the Site Address (URL) and WordPress Address (URL) to the same `http://wwwhello.com/`. And then I get logged out and get this error:

> The requested URL /wp-login.php was not found on this server.

I cannot access my site online nor my admin dashboard. What is the issue?

I tried renaming the .htaccess file to see if the problem is in it but it didn't help. In the wp-config.php I included these lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://wwwhello.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://wwwhello.com/);
```

It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you have mentioned occurs when WordPress login page is not being recognized or is missing. Make sure that the wp-login.php file is present in the root directory of your WordPress installation on the server. If it's missing, you might need to upload it again.

Comment: The wp-login.php file is present in the directory

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with the file structure or configuration of your WordPress site after transferring it to a new server.

I would recommend going through these steps to troubleshoot and potentially resolve the issue:

0. Ensure that WordPress is installed in the correct directory on your server. If WordPress is in a subdirectory (e.g., `/subdir`), the URLs should reflect that (e.g., `http://wwwhello.com/subdir/wp-login.php`
1. make sure all files are copied successfuly.
2. verify `.htaccess` file has the correct configuration you need for this server (check if yo have the same project structure and no additional nesting)
3. check your file permissions are set correctly, usually files should have `644` or `640`, and all directories `755` or `750`. [permissions](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions)
4. ensure you have no typos in wp-config.php for your `WP_HOME` or `WP_SITEURL` consts.
5. check your `php.ini` & apache/nginx (e.g., Apache's `httpd.conf` or Nginx's `nginx.conf`) config. purge you browser cache
6. check db prefix (When WordPress cannot correctly access or query its database due to a wrong database prefix, it can result in various errors or malfunctions on the site.)
7. double check your server error logs